# Saving a row in a many to many table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, many-to-many

I have 3 tables that form a many to many relationship as illustrated in the following image.

[image]

How can I save an entry in the UsersByCompanies table between company number 1 and user number 2, following the following rules:

- when we create a new entry between a user and a company, the IsEnabled attribute in UsersByCompanies must be set to 1 and any other rows where Companies.CompanyCode = 1 and Users.IDNumber = 2 must have their IsEnabled Attribute set to 0.
- The DateCreated attribute in the new row must have the current date.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an Insert Trigger and some default values:
When you insert into UsersByCompanies, use a Default Value on the IsEnabled column, and set an  insert trigger function to perform an update to reset the IsEnabled attributes as you require.
Likewise, use a default value of getdate() for the DateCreated attribute.